# How to extract authentication to separate function?

Tags: python, authentication, flask

I'm trying to implement a simple session based auth check like so:

```
@app.route("/home")
def home():

    if session.get('userID') is None:
        return redirect(url_for('login'))

    return render_template('home.html', uname = session['user'], userID = session['userID'])
```

This works, but I want to extract the check to it's own function and call it in multple routes, trying to keep the code DRY. When I replace

```
 if session.get('userID') is None:
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
```

with `auth_check()` and move the check in to

```
def auth_check()
 if session.get('userID') is None:
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
```

leaving me with

```
@app.route("/home")
def home():

    auth_check()

    return render_template('home.html', uname = session['user'], userID = session['userID'])
```

I get a key error on the session names when I load the page with no session, when I want it to just redirect as it does with the inline code. Something to do with how Flask handles routes? Not a massive deal but seems like an answer that lends itself to good principles for future reference.

Comment: You could define a closure (decorator) [like the choosen answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34495632/how-to-implement-login-required-decorator-in-flask)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, flask session works only in request scope. So you cannot go outside request processing function. But you can make a simple decorator that will authenticate requests.

Example of this decorator was already on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34499643/12181022