# Error 401 in Swagger UI for Flask Restplus API

Tags: python, swagger-ui, flask-restplus

I am building an API with `flask_restplus` and `flask_httpauth` for token based authentication. Everything is working nicely, except for one thing. In the Swagger UI, I get error 401 when I try to execute a search query. Adding "Bearer" to the authorization does not help. Please see the screenshot below.

The funny thing is, copy & pasting the output from `curl` (in the Swagger UI) and running it from the terminal does return the correct output. Same with running it in Postman. The problem is probably within the Swagger UI. Any suggestions?

The suggestion on [Github](https://github.com/noirbizarre/flask-restplus/issues/398#issuecomment-444336893) is unfortunately not working for me.

NB: it seems like `verify_token(token)` is not receiving input from the Swagger UI. When I try to print `token`, it is empty when being called from Swagger, but shows the value when being called from curl/Postman.

Part of the code:

```
authorizations = {
    'Bearer Auth': {
        'type': 'apiKey',
        'in': 'header',
        'name': 'Authorization'
    },
}

api = Api(blueprint, version='1.0', title='Flask API',
          description='My API', security='Bearer Auth', authorizations=authorizations)

@token_auth.verify_token
def verify_token(token):
    g.current_user = User.check_token(token) if token else None
    return g.current_user is not None
```

[image: Screenshot Swagger UI]

Comment: where exactly do you add your bearer token ?

Comment: via the "authorisatise" button (not visible in the screenshot, but the lock on the top right side indicates it). Adding a field under "A region name" is also possible, but didn't help...

Comment: I haven't tried this feature with login before requesting on swagger, but I still believe it is related to a malformed/ wrong bearer token..

Comment: Yes me too. The curl does work correctly though

Comment: And “token” remains empty while using Swagger

Comment: hmm.. you don't use something like request.args to retrieve the token ?

Comment: No. Would that need to be part of “verify_token”?

Comment: I based my comment on something similar to :
`@app.route('/api/gettoken', methods=['GET'])
def get_token():
    token = int(request.args['token'])
    pass`

if the token is empty, means it's not being retrieved no ?

Comment: You're not going to believe this. Safari was caching bad information :(
 Thanks for your help though!

Comment: wow ! 
well actually thanks to you now I know a new thing :)

Answer (score 0):

'Bearer Auth' must be replaced with just 'apikey'

see these links :

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xF30i_A6cRw&list=LLpaDwEA6bAAPZU5lz0ZRsuw&index=1
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WxGBoY5iNXY&list=LLpaDwEA6bAAPZU5lz0ZRsuw&index=3&t=2136s
- [How to implement login required decorator in Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34495632/how-to-implement-login-required-decorator-in-flask)