# Previously-set request cookies returns None in a Flask application

Tags: python, flask, cookies

I'm trying to store JWT Tokens in cookies for a Flask application to restrict some endpoints. An endpoint, "/authorize" , is responsible for setting the cookies then redirect the page to the root endpoint, "/".

```
from flask      import Flask, request, make_response, redirect

@app.route("/authorize", methods=["GET"])
def authorize():
   token       = request.args.get('token')
   expires     = request.args.get('expires')

   # some code to validate the token

   resp_output = make_response(redirect("/"))
   resp_output.set_cookie("token", token, expires=expires)

   return resp_output

@app.route("/", methods=["GET"])
def index():
   token = request.cookies.get("token)

   # do something with the token
```

However, when I tried to deploy this, I ran into some problems with the redirecting and therefore have to change `redirect("/")` to `redirect("https://someaddress.com/)"` where `https://someaddress.com/` is the address of the flask application. Now when I try to retrieve the token cookies in the root endpoint, it returns `None`. I suspect it is because the redirection has turnt from an internal one to an external one.

Please help me find a workaround for this. Or if you think I should resolve the problems that lead to the change from internal to external redirection so I can go back to what works. (If anyone can point me to some resources explaining exactly how redirection, or more specifically Flask's redirection, works, I'd really appreciate it.)

Answer (score 1):

Using `url_for` function from flask should work in your case, as it will look for the link within the app context:

```
from flask import Flask, request, make_response, redirect, url_for

@app.route("/authorize", methods=["GET"])
def authorize():
   token = request.args.get('token')
   expires = request.args.get('expires')

   # some code to validate the token

   resp_output = make_response(redirect(url_for('index')))
   resp_output.set_cookie("token", token, expires=expires)

   return resp_output

@app.route("/", methods=["GET"])
def index():
   token = request.cookies.get("token)

   # do something with the token
```

Btw, I would recommend you pass your authorization logic to a decorator, have a look on [authorization decorators using flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34495632/how-to-implement-login-required-decorator-in-flask).

In case this don't work in production, that can be some setting related to your reverse proxy - like nginx conf file. Let me know if it is the case

on Nginx file on sites-enabled folder `etc/nginx/sites-enabled/<project-name>`, comment or remove the following line:

```
proxy_set_header   Host                 $host;
```

Hope it suits you well!